# Phonegap windows phone page bounces on scrolling

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I am developing phone gap application for windows phone.
On application launch when I scroll on page then pages bounces vertically.
I want that page is fixed & non scroll-able.
Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can add the following code in the MainPage.xaml.cs file:

```
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        .... // some default initialization code was here
        // and disable bouncy scrolling option:
        this.CordovaView.DisableBouncyScrolling = true;
    }
```

Comment: In MainPage.xaml.cs page DisableBouncyScrolling is giving error

Comment: What Cordova version are you using?

Comment: I ma using Cordova 2.9

Comment: I'm using Cordova 2.9.1. Here is the application template: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ogtjjxlddqu4fby/ApplicationTemplate.zip You can find corresponding code in the MainPage.xaml.cs file.

Comment: Is there a way to disable this in the config.xml?

Comment: As for Cordova 2.9.1, if you look into the "\phonegap-2.9.1\lib\windows-phone\wp8\template\cordovalib\CordovaView.xaml.cs" file, you will see that DisableBouncyScrolling property value is not loaded from the "config.xml" file. I did not check it for modern versions.

Comment: Does not work for me. It disables all scrolling (pg 3.5). Should I manage scrolling with iScroll ?

Comment: Any ideas what is the MainPage.xaml.cs equivalent for the Windows Universal platform?