# Disable overscolling on cordova for windows phone 8

Tags: mobile, cordova, windows-phone-8, scroll, windows-phone

How to disable overscrolling in cordova 3.3.0 for windows phone 8?

I tried to add

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

or

```
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
```

in config.xml but to no avail. When I dragged the screen to the end, I can still pull the

screen and bounce it.

Can someone please show me some light on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like duplicate of the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837651/phonegap-windows-phone-page-bounces-on-scrolling/20854606?noredirect=1#comment35284098_20854606

Comment: yeap, I just saw this question thx for that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For stop UIBounce in windows or scrolling out you have to write code in MainPage.xaml.cs file so open this file from Solution Explorer and right below line in public MainPage() function

```
    this.CordovaView.DisableBouncyScrolling = true;
```

so after add this like your function should look like this

```
        public MainPage()
        {   InitializeComponent();
            this.CordovaView.DisableBouncyScrolling = true;
            this.CordovaView.Loaded += CordovaView_Loaded;
        }
```

**PS: Keep in mind that if you use this then your vertical scroll becomes a bit laggy.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, because I think my page has some content which is longer than a page on wp8, therefore I can still pull and bounce it. So i guess this won't work in that situation?

Comment: I can't believe I implemented this but it does not work on my WP 8.1, I still get the same annoying bouncing out of webview effect. Any suggestions pelase? I use CLI 3.6.3.

Comment: We are also facing the same problem as you said " vertical scroll becomes a bit laggy". How to overcome it ?